# How to increase smoothness of spheres3d in rgl

Tags: r, rgl

When I use `rgl::spheres3d()`, the rendered spheres have clunky facetted edges.

```
spheres = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(1,3,1),
                     color = c("#992222" , "#222299", "#229922"))
open3d()
spheres3d(spheres$x, spheres$y, radius = 1, color = spheres$color)
```

[image]

Setting `material3d(smooth = TRUE, line_antialias = TRUE)` does not improve this.  Increasing the radius does not help either.  Is there any way to increase the smoothness with which they are drawn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on [cuttlefish44's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39814263/2761575), I found a parameterization that works better - i.e. it has no defect at the poles (the black artifact on the lightblue sphere in the image).

```
library(rgl)
sphere.f <- function(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, z0 = 0, r = 1, n = 101, ...){
  f <- function(s, t) cbind(r * cos(s) * cos(t) + x0,
                            r * sin(s) * cos(t) + y0, 
                            r * sin(t) + z0)
  persp3d(f, slim = c(0, pi), tlim = c(0, 2*pi), n = n, add = T, ...)
}


sphere1.f <- function(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, z0 = 0, r = 1, n = 101, ...){
  f <- function(s,t){ 
    cbind(   r * cos(t)*cos(s) + x0,
             r *        sin(s) + y0,
             r * sin(t)*cos(s) + z0)
  }
  persp3d(f, slim = c(-pi/2,pi/2), tlim = c(0, 2*pi), n = n, add = T, ...)
}


sphere.f( -1.5,0, col = "lightblue")
sphere1.f( 1.5,0, col = "pink")
```

The image:

[image]

Comment: This is excellent - good job.  At n=101, the ridge defect around the equator is still there, but a good compromise between speed and quality. With n=201, its already hard to see. At n=301, barely discernible and still acceptably fast.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the correct answer vote. Would love to get a bronze badge in rgl, but at this rate it will take about 10 years.

Answer (score 4):

A much simpler approach is to use `subdivision3d()`.  Here, `depth=4` isn't all that smooth, but you could increase that.

```
library(rgl)
sphere <- subdivision3d(cube3d(),depth=4)
sphere$vb[4,] <- apply(sphere$vb[1:3,], 2, function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2)))
open3d()
shade3d(sphere, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Adding normals makes it look even better.  You can do this by adding `sphere$normals <- sphere$vb` for a sphere, or more generally `shape <- addNormals(shape)`.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this approach. And it can be improved by using `dodecahedron3d()` rather than `cube3d()`. Unfortunately, it does not work for high resolution spheres. If I increase depth above 6  I tend to get memory allocation errors. That said, dodecahedron3d at depth 6 looks pretty passable, if somewhat slow to process

Comment: Further to my last comment, adding @user2554330 's suggestion of adding normals to `icosahedron3d()` subdivided at depth 6, makes some pretty nice looking spheres

Answer (score 3):

Although `rgl::spheres3d()` can't do this, an alternative is to write your own function to draw spheres. Here is a function that renders a sphere as a grid of quadrilaterals spaced at equal degrees of latitude and longitude.

```
drawSphere = function(xc=0, yc=0, zc=0, r=1, lats=50L, longs=50L, ...) {
  #xc,yc,zc give centre of sphere, r is radius, lats/longs for resolution
  vertices = vector(mode = "numeric", length = 12L * lats * longs)
  vi = 1L
  for(i in 1:lats) {
    lat0 = pi * (-0.5 + (i - 1) / lats)
    z0   = sin(lat0)*r
    zr0  = cos(lat0)*r
    lat1 = pi * (-0.5 + i / lats)
    z1   = sin(lat1)*r
    zr1  = cos(lat1)*r
    for(j in 1:longs) {
      lng1 = 2 * pi *  (j - 1) / longs
      lng2 = 2 * pi *  (j) / longs
      x1 = cos(lng1)
      y1 = sin(lng1)
      x2 = cos(lng2)
      y2 = sin(lng2)
      vertices[vi] = x1 * zr0 + xc;    vi = vi + 1L
      vertices[vi] = y1 * zr0 + yc;    vi = vi + 1L 
      vertices[vi] = z0 + zc;          vi = vi + 1L
      vertices[vi] = x1 * zr1 + xc;    vi = vi + 1L
      vertices[vi] = y1 * zr1 + yc;    vi = vi + 1L
      vertices[vi] = z1 + zc;          vi = vi + 1L
      vertices[vi] = x2 * zr1 + xc;    vi = vi + 1L
      vertices[vi] = y2 * zr1 + yc;    vi = vi + 1L
      vertices[vi] = z1 + zc;          vi = vi + 1L
      vertices[vi] = x2 * zr0 + xc;    vi = vi + 1L
      vertices[vi] = y2 * zr0 + yc;    vi = vi + 1L
      vertices[vi] = z0 + zc;          vi = vi + 1L
    }
  }
  indices = 1:(length(vertices)/3)
  shade3d(qmesh3d(vertices, indices, homogeneous=F), ...)
}
```

It should be possible to improve on this, for example using [icospheres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7687312/2761575) (i.e. drawing the sphere as a stretched icosohedron). But this version already draws pretty good spheres if you make lats and longs high enough.

An example of the function in action:

```
spheres = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(1,3,1), z=c(0,0,0), color = c("#992222" , "#222299", "#229922"))
open3d() 
material3d(ambient = "black", specular = "grey60", emission = "black", shininess = 30.0)
rgl.clear(type = "lights")
rgl.light(theta = -30, phi = 60, viewpoint.rel = TRUE, ambient = "#FFFFFF", diffuse = "#FFFFFF", specular = "#FFFFFF", x = NULL, y = NULL, z = NULL)
rgl.light(theta = -0, phi = 0, viewpoint.rel = TRUE,  diffuse = "gray20", specular = "gray25", ambient = "gray80", x = NULL, y = NULL, z = NULL)
sapply(1:NROW(spheres), function(i) 
  drawSphere(spheres$x[i], spheres$y[i], spheres$z[i], r=1, lats = 400, longs = 400, color=spheres$color[i]))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, drawing your own sphere is the way to go. One possible improvement if you want just one colour is that you can draw just one sphere, and reuse it as a 3d sprite.  That saves memory, which probably doesn't matter in R, but will make a noticeable difference in file size if you export the scene using `rglwidget()`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my approach using `persp3d.function()`

```
sphere.f <- function(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, z0 = 0, r = 1, n = 101, ...){
  f <- function(s, t) cbind(r * cos(s) * cos(t) + x0,
                            r * sin(s) * cos(t) + y0, 
                            r * sin(t) + z0)
  persp3d(f, slim = c(0, pi), tlim = c(0, 2*pi), n = n, add = T, ...)
}

sphere.f(col = rainbow)
```

[image]

Comment: This makes some very nice smooth looking spheres, and is significantly faster to process than my qmesh3d based function.  The one thing holding me back from accepting this answer is that the spheres have defects around the poles, where there are gaps in the surface, and also a slight ridge at the equator where the two hemispheres don't quite match up.  Do you have any ideas about how to fix these issues?

Comment: @dww; Unfortunately it seems impossible. There some methods to express sphere with two variables. But low or high density area and/or duplicated points arise in any way.

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy; I *think* if you want to do this you're going to have to

- download the [rgl source from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rgl_0.96.0.tar.gz)
- unpack it and modify line 24 of `src/sphereSet.cpp`, which is currently

```
sphereMesh.setGlobe(16,16);
```

to call the function with some larger values (this function is defined on line 25 of `src/SphereMesh.cpp`; the arguments are `in_segments` and `in_sections` ...)

- build/install the package from source; this will require not only the standard compilation tools, but also the relevant OpenGL libraries (on a Debian Linux OS you could use `sudo apt-get build-dep r-cran-rgl` to get them, I think ...)

I haven't tried this. Good luck ... alternately, you could ask the package maintainer to make this a settable parameter via `materials3d` or in some other way ...

Comment: I would try downloading the source, editing the line mentioned above *and* the `DESCRIPTION` file (to set yourself to be the maintainer), and upload it up via ftp to `win-builder.r-project.org`

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use the `vcgSphere` function of the `Rvcg` package.

```
library(Rvcg)
sphr <- vcgSphere(subdivision = 4) # unit sphere centered at (0,0,0)
library(rgl)
shade3d(sphr, color="red")

# sphere with given radius and center
radius <- 0.5
center <- c(2,1,1)
sphr2 <- translate3d(
  scale3d(sphr, radius, radius, radius), 
  center[1], center[2], center[3])
shade3d(sphr2, color="green")
```

[image]